# Need Js code to check pipe "|" present in a string

Tags: javascript

hI 
I WANT a script TO CHECK atleast one occurrence of "|Viewed" word is present in js string.
sample  Js sting wolll be "22|Test|Viewed,22|Test|Un-Viewed,22|Test|Viewed".

can anyone help me out ?
THx

Comment: Do you mean js, or javascript?

Comment: @skaffman — JS is a perfectly acceptable abbreviation of JavaScript and doesn't have another meanings (except perhaps JScript, which is close enough to JavaScript as makes no difference in most cases, and should be explicitly mentioned anyway in the cases where it does).

Comment: There is a language called JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148979/working-with-a-severely-limited-interpreted-language Where is your god now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have already mentioned indexOf where you can do:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript">
    var str="22|Test|Viewed,22|Test|Un-Viewed,22|Test|Viewed";
    document.write(str.indexOf("|Viewed"));
</script></body></html>
```

but I'd like to also mention a more powerful option (if needed) - you can use the regex string search method:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript">
    var str="22|Test|Viewed,22|Test|Un-Viewed,22|Test|Viewed";
    document.write(str.search("\\|Viewed"));
</script></body></html>
```

Typing either of these into a file (`xx.html`) and loading it in your browser, you'll see the number 7 appear which is the first position of the string found. This value is zero-based (0 is the first position) and you'll get back -1 if it cannot be found.

The regex version will allow more complex search patterns, not necessary for this specific case, but you should keep it in mind for when a simple constant string may not suffice.

Comment: Eugh. Using a regular expression for a simple pattern match is inefficient … and despite the documentation saying you need to pass in a regex ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/search ) , you are passing in a string … and you've escaped the `\` so its going to be looking for `\|Viewed` instead of `|Viewed` (or are you using some implementation of search that `eval`s strings in to regular expressions in that context (which is also dirty and should be avoided).

Comment: I suggest you try it, David, it works just fine. You _don't_ have to pass in a regex, one will be created for you if necessary. In addition, I didn't want to parrot just what had already been said, rather to provide a more powerful approach when needed. indexOf is fine for fixed strings and I congratulate you on your answer but sometimes I need more power. The double backslash is required because it's in a string so that the double becomes a single, and the single followed by the vertical bar is so we treat the bar as a specific character rather than the "or" separator.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript">
    var my_string = "22|Test|Viewed,22|Test|Un-Viewed,22|Test|Viewed";
    var the_matchIndex = my_string.indexOf('|Viewed');
    var blMatch = the_matchIndex > -1;
    alert(blMatch ? "Found a match!" : "No match found");
</script></body></html>
```